# Local Notification for specific date and time is not working. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unnotificationrequest

I am trying to trigger a local notification on a specific date and time on button click but it's not working. Below is the code:

```
@IBAction func setReminderBtnPressed (_ sender: UIButton) {
    var dateString = String()
    dateString = "2018-10-20 18:11:00"
    //let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60) //Working Fine
    let date = globalMethods.convertStringToDate(dateStr: dateString) //log 2018-10-20 10:11:00 +0000 
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Don't forget"
    content.body = "Buy some milk"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date) //log ▿ year: 2018 month: 10 day: 20 hour: 18 minute: 11 second: 0 isLeapMonth: false
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Something went wrong
            print(error)
        }
    })
}

func convertStringToDate(dateStr: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current// (abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
    let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
    print("dateFromString: ", dateFromString!)
    return dateFromString!
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No error message, you can check log written next to the code in the comment.

Comment: Yes, I can see but when I print log for triggerDate then it shows correctly. You can check log printed to the next code.

Comment: Edited the code. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have authorized the app to send notifications to the user.

In your **AppDelegate**'s `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, request for the authorization:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (success, error) in
    if let error = error {
        debugPrint("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

And, confirm to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in your **AppDelegate**, and implement the method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    completionHandler(.alert)
}
```